# My EC2 Ubuntu instance has not internet access?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So im new to ec2 and aws , i created a account yesterday and opened a ubuntu instance, i can update and upgrade  or install new packages but the problem comes when using a api that connects to a game api

https://gitlab.com/man90/black-desert-social-rest-api

I build and run api on the instance and runs normal.

Problem is when calling the api for some reason i get 404 not found response.

```
    Used configuration:
    Proxies:        []
    Port:           8001
    Cache TTL:      180 minutes

2021/12/30 07:34:29 Listening for requests
```

but when calling api from python i got 404 not found response, so ec2 instance cannot resolve domain or is unrecehable.

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX:~/bdo/guild-scraping$ python3 gsheet.py
404 page not found
```

if i ping the page from ec2 instance works as normal, but for some reason, running api and calling it from python is giving error

```
 ubuntu@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX:~/bdo/guild-scraping$ ping www.naeu.playblackdesert.com
PING ds7lduf.impervadns.net (45.223.17.187) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 45.223.17.187 (45.223.17.187): icmp_seq=1 ttl=33 time=8.27 ms
64 bytes from 45.223.17.187 (45.223.17.187): icmp_seq=2 ttl=33 time=8.15 ms
64 bytes from 45.223.17.187 (45.223.17.187): icmp_seq=3 ttl=33 time=8.13 ms
64 bytes from 45.223.17.187 (45.223.17.187): icmp_seq=4 ttl=33 time=8.18 ms
64 bytes from 45.223.17.187 (45.223.17.187): icmp_seq=5 ttl=33 time=8.16 ms
```

if i ping the api outside my code from python happens the same, so idk if my code cannot reach api for some reason or api itself cannot reach internet game website.

```
 import requests
 r = requests.get("http://localhost:8001/v1/guild", params=payload)
 print(r.text)
404 page not found
```

Answer (score 2):

`404` error means that the server is found and reached but the server responded that it can't find the resource requested.